# Difference between 1 and true

Tags: php, api

I am trying to use this PHP script to get the shortened link from bit.ly API.. It works fine but my question is there any way to make this script more efficient or take some unnecessary parts out of it. Also my main question is that when I use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

I have to use the trim function on $data but when I use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

I don't have to do that.. Why is it causing a line break after the link when I use 1 instead of true?

```
<?php
function get_bitly_short_url($url, $format = 'txt')
{
    $connectURL = 'http://api.j.mp/v3/shorten?login=(MY USERNAME)&apiKey=(MY API)&uri=' . urlencode($url) . '&format=' . $format;
    return curl_get_result($connectURL);
}
function curl_get_result($url)
{
    $ch      = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return trim($data);
}
$short_url = get_bitly_short_url('http://google.com');
?>
```

Comment: There should be no difference between `true` and `1` as parameter to `curl_setopt`.  As for making things simpler, I suspect you've got what you need, it's not larger and it's simple - don't try to fix what's not broken.

Comment: That is what I was thinking too because true in binary format is 1 but the 1 is causing a line break when I change it to true.. it doesn't cause a line break

Comment: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option's value should be bool, else behavior can be undefined ;) [Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: `1 !== true` in common case, but in your case, should be no difference, double check all other things...

Comment: `1 == true` is true but `1 === true` is false. As said above, it shouldn't make a difference in the case above.

Comment: so it should either be 0 or 1? But how would that explain the line break?

Comment: Line break at the end? Anyway there should be no difference between true and 1 in this case. Maybe that some kind of PHP bug, or maybe with 1 it threats response as text (and put linebreak at the end) and in case of true if threats file as binary... strange.

Comment: so if I echo "short_url"... there is a line break like this: ('http://google.com (line break) ');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 !== true in common case, but in your case, should be no difference,
>   double check all other things...

I make simple test for you:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://ziptasticapi.com/92530';

    $ch      = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $ch      = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $data1 = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    var_dump($data);
    echo "\n";
    var_dump($data1);
```

Results:

> string(52) "{"country":"US","state":"CA","city":"LAKE ELSINORE"}"
>   string(52) "{"country":"US","state":"CA","city":"LAKE ELSINORE"}"

So, bugs in php happens, but no bugs this time
No difference, check other parts of your system
Luck!

Comment: hmmm... It works fine with your code but now I am starting to think that the line break might be caused because of my $connectURL code...